# Embedding javascript file within a shiny app www subdirectory does not work

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

Seems like shiny cannot recognize my .js file. Question is why?

Inlined js script text runs smoothly:

```r
library(shiny)

header = dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

body = dashboardBody(
    
    shiny::tags$script(
        HTML("document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'skyblue';")),
)

ui = dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body)

server = function(input, output, session){

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However when i embedd my .js file (myscript.js stored within www subdirectory)

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";

  $("firstinput").on("keypress", function(){
      alert("Pressed");
    })
  
  $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
  alert('Connected to the server'); 
    })
```

...like this:

```
library(shiny)

header = dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

body = dashboardBody(
    
    shiny::tags$head(
        shiny::tags$script(
            src = "myscript.js"
        )),
        
        HTML('<input type="button" id="firstinput">')
)

ui = dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body)

server = function(input, output, session){
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

nothing is applied... How comes?

Comment: Note that `$("firstinput")` should be `$("#firstinput")` instead. But I don't think this is the cause of the problem. Your code should work. Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: your right and I already tried with `$("#firstinput")` but it does not work. When I go with `tags$script(src = "myscript.js")` instead of `tags$head`, `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";` and  `$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {alert('Connected to the server');})` are running though

Answer (score 0):

No need of `tags$head()`.  The following works fine.

`tags$script(src = "myscript.js")`

Comment: It's true there's no need of `tags$head` but I don't see why this would prevent the code to work. Perhaps a `$(document).ready` is necessary for the two first statements of JavaScript, but the third one should throw the alert. No?

Comment: As @StéphaneLaurent mentioned, I do not see why this would prevent the code to work either. And the the exclusion of `tags$head` does not have any drawbacks, since the script is not embedded in the header? For example when I embed other js libraries such as jBox I do also embed it in the header with `tags$head(tags$script(src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.2.0/dist/jBox.all.min.js'))` and it works just fine.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, You are correct.  With `$(document).ready` it works fine with `tags$head`.  His current `myscript.js`, as shown in OP, only works without `tags$head`.